# PHP-DI inject parameter by name

Tags: php, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, php-di

I am using php-di and Doctrine together. To use Doctrine there is a `bootstrap.php` file which constructs the `$entityManager` object. The `$entityManager` object is defined globally in that file so to use it in my classes I have to inject it.

For example assume the class below:

```
<?php
interface IAccountService{
    function login(string $username, string $password);
}
class AccountService implements IAccountService {

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function login(string $email, string $password){
        $q = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('us.id, us.name, us.email, us.passwordHashed')
            ->from('User', 'us')
            ->where('us.email = ?1 AND us.passwordHashed = ?2')
            ->setMaxResults( '1' )
            ->setParameter(1,$email)
            ->setParameter(2, HASHHELPER::hashPasswordSHA512($password, $email))
            ->getQuery();

        // echo $q->getSql();

        $users = $q->getResult();

        // print_r($users);

        if(!empty($users) && count($users) > 0){
            $_SESSION["USER"] = $users[0];
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But the type of `$entityManager` is not well defined and either when I call `echo gettype($entityManager);` it prints `"object"` as result. So I think I need to inject this parameter by its name instead of its type. I mean something like this:

```
$container->set('$entityManager', $entityManager);
```

But this does not work. What's the solution and the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem have solved after facing [this link](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html) which shows the namespace and class name of `$entityManager` but the question of injecting according to variable name is still open. By now, the new source code of mine is like this:

AccountService.php

```
<?php
interface IAccountService{
    function login(string $username, string $password);
}
class AccountService implements IAccountService {

    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface $entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function login(string $email, string $password){
        $q = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('us.id, us.name, us.email, us.passwordHashed')
            ->from('User', 'us')
            ->where('us.email = ?1 AND us.passwordHashed = ?2')
            ->setMaxResults( '1' )
            ->setParameter(1,$email)
            ->setParameter(2, HASHHELPER::hashPasswordSHA512($password, $email))
            ->getQuery();

        // echo $q->getSql();

        $users = $q->getResult();

        // print_r($users);

        if(!empty($users) && count($users) > 0){
            $_SESSION["USER"] = $users[0];
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

routes.php

```
<?php
  spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    switch ($class_name){
      case 'AccountController':
        require_once 'controllers/account_controller.php';
        break;
      case 'AccountService':
      case 'IAccountService':
        require_once 'services/account_service.php';
        break;
      case 'URLHELPER':
        require_once 'helpers/URLHELPER.php';
        break;
      case 'STRINGHELPER':
        require_once 'helpers/STRINGHELPER.php';
        break;
      case 'HASHHELPER':
        require_once "helpers/HASHHELPER.php";
        break;
      case 'User':
        require_once "models/entities/user.php";
        break;
    }
  });

  function call($controller, $action) {
    global $entityManager;
    $container = DI\ContainerBuilder::buildDevContainer();
    $container->set('IAccountService', \DI\object('AccountService'));
    $container->set('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface', $entityManager);

    // require the file that matches the controller name
    require_once('controllers/' . $controller . '_controller.php');

    // create a new instance of the needed controller
    switch($controller) {
      case 'home':
        $controller = $container->get('HomeController');
        break;
      case 'account':
        $controller = $container->get('AccountController');
        break;
      default:
        $controller = 'home';
        $action = 'index';
    }

    // call the action
    $controller->{ $action }();
  }

  // just a list of the controllers we have and their actions
  // we consider those "allowed" values
  $controllers = array(
    'home' => ['index', 'error']
    ,'account' => ['login']
  );

  // check that the requested controller and action are both allowed
  // if someone tries to access something else he will be redirected to the error action of the pages controller
  if (array_key_exists($controller, $controllers)) {
    if (in_array($action, $controllers[$controller])) {
      call($controller, $action);
    } else {
      call('home', 'error');
    }
  } else {
    call('home', 'error');
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you show how are you injecting EntityManager now?

Also, it's a good practice to use type-hinting:

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

UPDATE:

Ok, I usually use PHP-DI with a PHP configuration file (http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html). It would look something like this:

```
return [
AccountService::class => DI\object(AccountService::class)->constructor("here goes EntityManager object")
];
```

Comment: As I mentioned I don't have a typing like `EntityManager` you've added. And I am not injecting it now. It is the question.

Comment: You mean something like this (?) : `$container->set('IAccountService', \DI\object('AccountService')->contructor($entityManager));` I think this is a bad solution. Because I should inject all the paramaeters of `AccountService` by hand and change this definition anytime I change `AccountService`. More problematic when I use this $entityManager in many classes like `AccountService`! Am I wrong?

Comment: Both answers proposed by @Sauron1953 are correct, either type-hint the parameter or write a configuration file. You want to do `->contructor(\DI\get('EntityManager'))` that way you define the dependency `'EntityManager'` separately (with a [closure](http://php-di.org/doc/php-definitions.html#factories) for example).

Comment: @ConductedClever Yes, you have to do changes by hand, but you make them only at one place. If you could use type-hinting, the autowiring would do that magic for you.

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli I think without specifying the type `EntityManager` I your solution can't be used too.

Comment: @Sauron1953 thanks to your solution, I have voted your solution up. But the question of injecting by variable name is open.

Comment: I'm quite sure that you can't inject according to variable name.

Comment: @Sauron1953 so I think this is the answer. Have you seen any document about this?

Comment: @ConductedClever Actually, check this: http://php-di.org/doc/inject-on-instance.html  I don't have my business laptop at the moment , so I can't test it.

Comment: @ConductedClever you can't inject by parameter name (source: I'm the author of PHP-DI)

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli (the author of php-di), thanks for your clarification.